# How to play a sound after an operation is complete taking longer than n seconds

Tags: r

I want to be able to have a sound play after an operation is completed if the operation took longer than n seconds. I am using RStudio if that helps. TIA.

Comment: I think you could find that with some research. Just research: 1) how to play sound in RStudio, and 2, how to time. Then call the sound function after that time. I'm just saying you could solve the problem easily on your own.

Comment: See `beepr` package

Comment: @AnilGoyal What does this have to do with the IDE?

Comment: @Phil I apologize for assuming it that OP wants to play beep in IDE. Thanks for pointing it out. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_operation <- function() {
  start_time = Sys.time()
  
  # the thing I need to do taking uncertain time
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, max = 4))

  time_taken  = Sys.time() - start_time
  
  if(time_taken > 3) {
    beepr::beep("mario")
    Sys.sleep(1) # I've had R crash if play a beepr sound w/o 
                 #   a sleep in non-interactive mode
  }
  
  time_taken
}
```

Then if you run

```
my_operation()
```

it will take 0-4 seconds to run the imaginary task. If it takes more than 3 seconds it will make  a sound.